# I need to generate x random numbers in an interval from 1 to x but each number have to occur only once

Tags: python, random, numbers, generated

I need to generate a random number, actually i need 70128 random numbers form 1 to 70128. Here is what I'm using:

```
index = numpy.random.randint(1,70128,70128)
```

The other thing is, that I need each number between 1 and 70128 to be generated only once.

This means that I need a list of 70128 random generated numbers between 1 and 70128 but each number have to occur only once.

Comment: Glad you found both answers helpful! Do take into account you can only pick one as *most helpful to you*, not both. Which answer gets the checkmark is entirely up to you!

Comment: You don't want random numbers at all. You want precisely the numbers 1..70128, *in random order*. This is called shuffling, as in what one does to a deck of cards. Create an array, then use random.shuffle().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy's `random.permutation` function, which, if given a single scalar argument `x`, will return a random permutation of the numbers from 0 to `x`. For instance:

```
np.random.permutation(10)
```

Gives:

```
array([3, 2, 8, 7, 0, 9, 6, 4, 5, 1])
```

So, in particular, `np.random.permutation(70128) + 1` does precisely what you'd like.

Comment: I get this error when I'm doing it

IndexError: index 70128 is out of bounds for size 70128

Answer (score 3):

You you need `x` random numbers between `1` and `x` that are all unique then you just want a *shuffled range*:

```
x = 70128
numbers = range(1, x + 1)
random.shuffle(numbers)
```

If you are using Python 3, you want to add a `list()` call to the `range()` result.

Demo on Python 2.7 with `x = 10` for practicality:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = 10
>>> numbers = range(1, x + 1)
>>> random.shuffle(numbers)
>>> numbers
[5, 2, 6, 4, 1, 9, 3, 7, 10, 8]
```

Comment: I get this error when I'm doing it

IndexError: index 70128 is out of bounds for size 70128

Comment: @SmailKozarcanin: Python indexes start at 0, so you can index the list from 0 through to 70127; the last index is always `len(listobj) - 1`.